# link is not clickable when i am using position absolue with two images(only first is clickable )

Tags: html, css, absolute

please give idea for multiple images is clickable using.
please, help in the following code.

```
 <style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image:url('Banner.png');
         background-repeat:no-repeat; 
        background-size:auto auto;
}
</style>
<div>
<span style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;">
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="logo.png" height="70px" width=""></a></span>
<span style="position:absolute;left:170px;top:10px;">
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com.in/" target="_blank" >
<img src="DM.png" height="70px" width="" >
</a>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no issue. They are both clickable. [FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9L9qwag/)

Answer (score 0):

your link is wrong

change `http://www.yahoo.com.in/` `to http://www.yahoo.co.in/`

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.co.in/" target="_blank" >
   <img src="DM.png" height="70px" width="" >
</a>
```

your links are clickable

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/uskr70Lx/)

Comment: sir, image is not clickable.code is same as above.link is also i have corrected.but,in body i have applied background image .         as body{background:url('some.png');}

Comment: i think something is overlapping on your 2nd a tag

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working fine in **Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120** & **Mozilla Firefox version 33.0** both the browswer

Just write **http://www.yahoo.co.in** instead of **http://www.yahoo.com.in/**

Here is the Demo:

> **jsfiddle.net/ob0oona2/3/**